# Display all password rules custom Data Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Hello I have set up a custom password rule via data annotation. It works, however, it would be nice to display all the error messages to the user if the password requirements are not met.

My code follows this -

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string password = value.ToString();

        if (password.Length < 8)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Password must contain at least 8 characters");
        }
        if (password.Count(c => char.IsLower(c)) == 0)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Password must contain a lowercase character");
        }
        //other password rules removed for berevity
        else
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

So how would I show both if statements say if the password has no lowercase characters and is less than 8 characters instead of just returning that first if statement?

Comment: How is this called?

Comment: @JamesS It is a custom data annotation the password field is decorated with the class name
       `[Required]
        [PasswordPolicy]
        public string Password { get; set; }`
and this then gets called on the view when the model validation fails on the controller `if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return UnprocessableEntity(ModelState);
            }`

Comment: Here is a good summary on one way to do this: https://andrewlock.net/creating-custom-password-validators-for-asp-net-core-identity-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save all error messages in one string and return it after checking all rules.

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string password = value.ToString();
        var errorMessage = "";

        if (password.Length < 8)
        {
            errorMessage += "Password must contain at least 8 characters.";             
        }
        if (password.Count(c => char.IsLower(c)) == 0)
        {
            errorMessage += "Password must contain a lowercase character.";
        }
        //other rules
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
        }
    }
```